# find a substring and then replace it with something else probably with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need some help on regex. I'm working on some twitter data and there are a lot of tweets that contain text like this: #something1@something2 . I'm trying to find a way to find substrings like that and replace it with #something1 @something2. I use python 3.
How can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you been through the regex tutorial provided with Python more than once? https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use look-behind to check there is a non-space:

```
s = re.sub(r'(?<=\S)@', ' @', s)
```

To only do this if there is a "connected" `#`:

```
s = re.sub(r'(#\S+)@', r'\1 @', s)
```

Comment: This doesn't find valid hashtags and usernames, it will *break* emails for example. But it appears to be valid for the op, leaving my answer for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to find a hashtag and a username that are **not** separated by a space and change them to be separated by a space. Indeed we can use a regular expression to match those.

```
sourceTweet = "lorem ipsum #dolor@sitamet Nullam sed est #vel@mi "
outputTweet = re.sub(r'(?<!\w)(#\w+)(@\w+)', r'\1 \2', sourceTweet)
#lorem ipsum #dolor @sitamet Nullam sed est #vel @mi
```